# Align EditText to Start at the Top Left of Space - Android C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-edittext, gravity

I have an `EditText` with multiple lines inside an `AlertDialog`, but I cannot get the words to start typing from the Top Left of the EditText programmatically.

How would I get the Gravity to align at the Top Left Programmatically?

[image: EditText Example]

Answer (score 1):

Set gravity of edittext in xml

```
android:gravity="top"
```

Or in C# code

```
edittext.Gravity = GravityFlags.Top;
```

Comment: It does not have an XML file, it is just declared in the OnCreate for use in the Alert Dialog... So is there a way to do it via C#

Comment: **Try this**

`edittext.Gravity = GravityFlags.Top;`

Comment: Can you please post xaml?

Comment: There is no `axml` as I have declared the `EditText` inside the `OnCreate` method. The `EditText` is not in any layout, it only exists inside the `MainActivity.cs`

Comment: What is the height and width of `EditText`?